# Indigo installation ask for Ubuntu 14.04 cd/dvd

Tags: ros, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, desktop-full

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i m at the step when we install using apt-install, but before it cld install anything it asks me to insert installation disk that i do not have, rather i do have a pendrive that is boot ready ubuntu setup. how can i use it instead or rather if cld just skip the step and system download packages online.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191021/indigo-installation-ask-for-ubuntu-14.04-cd/dvd/) by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is with 'Software Sources' setting. Refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install) for answer.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2